# TypeError: target is null in noUISLider

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, nouislider

I am using noUISlider - http://refreshless.com/nouislider/ . When adding the slider `nouislider.js` via enqueue script in `Wordpress` i get following `javascript` error in firebug -

```
TypeError: target is null

if ( !target.nodeName ) {
```

Here i how enqueued the script -

```
wp_register_script('realstate-noui', BRPC_BASE_URL . 'js/nouislider.js');
wp_enqueue_script('realstate-noui');
```

The code of `nouislider.js` where error is happening -

```js
function initialize ( target, originalOptions ) {

  if ( !target.nodeName ) {
   throw new Error('noUiSlider.create requires a single element.');
  }

  // Test the options and create the slider environment;
  var options = testOptions( originalOptions, target ),
   slider = closure( target, options );

  // Use the public value method to set the start values.
  slider.set(options.start);

  target.noUiSlider = slider;
 }

 // Use an object instead of a function for future expansibility;
 return {
  create: initialize
 };
```